# Can't retrieve image name from metadata server

Tags: google-compute-engine

I'm trying to get image name from metadata, but the server's answer is empty. It worked couple of days ago. I tried both old metadata url and new

```
[root@mys-pike ~]# curl http://metadata/computeMetadata/v1beta1/instance/image
[root@mys-pike ~]# curl -is http://metadata/computeMetadata/v1beta1/instance/image
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Content-Type: application/text
ETag: 3c19e4d76229ba8c
Date: Wed, 12 Jun 2013 14:56:46 GMT
Server: Metadata Server for VM
Content-Length: 0
X-XSS-Protection: 1; mode=block
X-Frame-Options: SAMEORIGIN

[root@mys-pike ~]# curl  http://metadata/0.1/meta-data/image
[root@mys-pike ~]# curl -is  http://metadata/0.1/meta-data/image
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Content-Type: application/text
Date: Wed, 12 Jun 2013 15:02:02 GMT
Server: Metadata Server for VM
Content-Length: 0
X-XSS-Protection: 1; mode=block
X-Frame-Options: SAMEORIGIN

[root@mys-pike ~]# curl http://metadata/0.1/meta-data/instance-id
10970436504468444993
```

Comment: That metadata query works fine on a Debian VM I just created - I wonder if something might be corrupted on your VM. Do you know when this VM was created and which image it uses? Could you try creating a new VM with the same image and seeing if this persists? If it does, I'd suggest sending your project id and VM name, along with this description, to gc-team@google.com.

Comment: Looks like everything is back to normal. Like i said, it worked earlier, and now it works again. I guess google guys fixed this problem, thank you!

Answer (score 1):

If instance was created from the snapshot then image field in metadata is empty.

Answer (score 1):

Are you booting your VM from a persistent disk?

If so, what does the Compute Engine API report in the JSON instance output for the boot disk?  You can check this with the gcutil tool using `gcutil --print_json getinstance` if you're mostly using the command-line tools, or look at the equivalent REST in the GUI.

If you've booted from a persistent disk, the [`source` attribute](https://developers.google.com/compute/docs/reference/latest/instances#resource) on the boot disk should point to a persistent disk.  You can then fetch the [persistent disk resource](https://developers.google.com/compute/docs/reference/latest/disks#resource) and check the `sourceImage` parameter to determine whether Compute Engine knows that the disk was created from a particular image.